# How do I create a function that creates different structs based on parameters?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

While writing a personal C++ project, I stumbled upon an interesting problem that I don't know how to handle, or if it's even possible and I have to change my ways of doing things.

Here's a snippet of entity component system themed code, ignore if it's not the best way to make an ECS because that's just an example that I think should make sense:

```
struct entity
{
    //entity data
};

struct component
{
    //basic component data
};

struct transform : public component
{
    //transform data
};

struct rigidbody : public component
{
    //rb data
};

struct sprite : public component
{
    //sprite data
};

class entityManager
{
public:
        entityManager(aWindow nWindow);

        void initComponent(component* nComponent); //takes any derived struct and puts its name into the componentList vector which also gives it an id, i could change that

        void createEntity(std::string nName); //'entities.push_back(entity("name"))'

        void addComponent(unsigned int componentId, unsigned int entityId);

private:
        aWindow window;
        std::vector<std::string> componentList;
        std::vector<entity> entities;
        std::vector<component*> components;
};
```

`addComponent` is the issue. I have no clue on how can I write that function to create a component of any type of these three above and put it into the `components` vector. Is that even possible? I read that it's possible to store any struct that is derived from the base class which is named `component` here in a vector but how do I create and add structs to it based on an ID, name or something? I can make a switch with every id and appropriate code like `components.push_back(rigidbody("foo"))` but that isn't modular at all and I would have to add new switch cases with each new component. One way would be if I could change the std::string name of a component into a part of code but that's just a ridiculous concept, especially with C++.

Comment: "*I can make a switch with every id*" It's all going to be some variation of that. Whether you write a switch or get some code to write a switch for you, a switch is happening.

Comment: you may consider polymorphism depending on your needs.  may involve some virtual functions (destructors!) and lots of pointers (vector of pointers that deletes its members if they should be owned).  if your classes are specific enough, there are even ways to identify them at runtime.  `components.push_back(new rigidbody("foo"))`

Comment: You may want to check how to implement a *factory* in the OOP world. It's usually done with one switch case, I don't see any maintainability issue in that.

Comment: I'll check the factory thing out, i thought a switch will be problematic here if i would make let's say a UI for the whole thing and the user would add these new components but yeah i guess that's one way, considering im starting out c++ and terms mentioned here by @Abel like polymorphism or virtual functions are completely unknown for me.

Comment: okay sorry i checked the definition of polymorphism and virtual functions, i actually mostly know what these are i just wasn't exposed to these names haha

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/TT7vjqfv3)'s a code example to get you started!

Comment: :O that is super helpful, thanks a lot!!